# Scripting structure for unity with airconsole

Tags: unity-game-engine, airconsole

I've looked at the examples that come with the airconsole plugin, and in both of the examples the "meat" of the code is in one script.

I am interested in trying to make a multiplayer game, is it possible to split the control of each character into 4 scripts, which each are applied on a different player object rather than having one script control all 4 objects from one single script?

If so, how do you go about doing it, just by including the libraries in each control script? like so:

```
using NDream.AirConsole;
```

or do i have to do some kind of special structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to have various different scripts that use the NDream.AirConsole namespace, yes.
Be aware however that if you have 4 scripts in a scene that all listen for the OnMessage event, for instance, you will likely end up using a lot more performance than if you just have one "AirConsole script" in a scene, where you receive and filter the messages and then relay to the right player.

Better to have one AirConsole script that listens for the event, check for device id/player number in the OnMessage (or whichever) event and then send the relevant information to the player script in question.

That's how we do it for our multiplayer games in Unity.

Comment: Thanks that asnwers my question, i'll get back to tinkering, and hopefully make it work